# How to change input of a tensorflow.layers.dense() layer?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

In tensorflow layers.dense(inputs, units, activation) implements a Multi-Layer Perceptron layer with arbitrary activation function. 
Say i defined my dense layer like this:

```
inputx = tf.placeholder(float, shape=[batch_size, input_size])
dense_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputx, 128, tf.nn.relu)
```

Now later i want to feed it some other input, say after restoring it from a checkpoint or just merely in the same graph for some reason:

```
inputx_2 = tf.some_operation(whatever_thisdoes, shape = [batch_size_2, input_size])
inputx = tf.placeholder(float, shape=[batch_size, input_size])
dense_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputx, 128, tf.nn.relu)
```

How could i now get dense_layer and it's possibly already pretrained weights to apply to inputx_2? (Without assigning input_y the value of inputx_2 if possible?)
Would having a different batch_size (batch_size_2 instead of batch_size) cause any trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'name' and 'reuse' argument to achieve this behaviour:

```
inputx = tf.placeholder(float, shape=[batch_size, input_size])
inputx_2 = tf.some_operation(whatever_thisdoes, shape = [batch_size_2, input_size])

dense_layer = tf.layers.dense(inputx, 128, tf.nn.relu, name='dense_layer')
dense_layer2 = tf.layers.dense(inputx_2, 128, tf.nn.relu, name='dense_layer', reuse=True)
```

Both dense_layer and dense_layer2 share weights thanks to the 'reuse' attribute, but dense_layer is applied to input_x and dense_layer2 to inputx_2.

> Would having a different batch_size (batch_size_2 instead of batch_size) cause any trouble?

No. You can verify this easily:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    out = dense_layer.eval({inputx: np.ones([batch_size, input_size])})
    out2 = dense_layer2.eval({inputx_2: np.ones([batch_size_2, input_size])})
    assert np.array_equal(out[0,:], out2[0,:])
```

I advise you to create a forward pass function to easily reproduce this behaviour for all your models, for example:

```
def forward_pass(x, name='Model', reuse=False):
     with tf.variable_scope(name, reuse=reuse):
         x = tf.some_ops(x, ...)
         ...
     return x
```

You can then pass any tensor to forward pass, in your case:

```
 out = forward_pass(inputx)
 out2 = forward_pass(inputx_2, reuse=True)
```